# Regex not capturing character

Tags: regex

I'm not good at Regex, but I was asked to edit an existing one to account for a certain character (,).

Original: `[^ -~]`

The way I read this: Any character not in between &#32 and &#126. The comma is &#44

My new regex:

```
[^ -+]&[^--~]
```

The way I read this: Any character not in between &#32 and &#43 AND any character not in between &#45 and &#126

But the new regex does not seem to be valid for my case.

Comment: &#... - please put in the actual characters (I am assumming you are using HTML markup)

Comment: `&` is not a special character in regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new regex actually looks for a character not in space to `+`, followed by an `&`, followed by a character not in `-` to `~`. What you should do instead is to combine your two ranges into one character class:

```
[^ -+--~]
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rriZtM/2)

You could also use an alternation to allow for `,`:

```
,|[^ -~]
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rriZtM/3)